# Rails console into Docker on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, docker, heroku-toolbelt

I've got a Rails app on a Docker image deployed to Heroku using `heroku docker:release`. I normally use `heroku run rails console` to access the console, but I am getting `bash: /app/user/bin/rails: Permission denied`.  How do I access the Rails console via the Heroku-CLI command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heroku run bundle exec rails console`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
docker-compose run web rails c
```